# How do you keep neural networks training intact?

Tags: c++, neural-network

I've been experimenting with neural networks in `C++` in implementing a network that plays and learns tic-tac-toe. A problem I have run into, and that I have been wondering about is, how do you keep a network with it's "memory" or learnt skills, intact, once you end the program/training? At the moment it learns as you keep playing, but once I close the program and restart it. It's stupid again. How do I get around this, and how do other large neural networks get around this problem?

Comment: Good idea. Make it know there is no way to win WWIII before it begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory of a neural network is stored in the weights of its connections. If you want to prevent it from forgetting what it learnt you need to serialize these weights in a file or a database.